# Any ideas why MyStack doesn't conform to ProtoStack?

Tags: swift

I have put together what should have been a simple piece of sample in an Xcode 8β2 playground.  Unfortunately, I can't see why the `struct` does not conform to the `protocol`.  I'm sure it's something very simple but can't, for the life of me, see it.

```
protocol ProtoStack {

    associatedtype ItemType

    func push(item: ItemType)
    func pop() -> ItemType
    func isEmpty() -> Bool
    func size() -> Int
}

struct MyStack: ProtoStack {

    var contents = [Int]()

    typealias ItemType = Int

    mutating func push(item: Int) { contents.append(item) }
    mutating func pop() -> Int { return contents.popLast()! }
    func isEmpty() -> Bool { return contents.count == 0 }
    func size() -> Int { return contents.count }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mark your `push` and `pop` protocol requirements as `mutating`

Comment: Ah, I see.  Interesting.  That implies that MyStack - as written above - can only be implemented by a class.  If I add the mutating keyword to the protocol then it can only be implemented by a struct.  [Edit:  Tried it and the protocol can be implemented by both a class and a struct, if the protocol uses the mutating keyword.]

(Make your comment an answer and I'll credit it.)

Comment: The `mutating` keyword doesn't imply that it can only be implemented by a struct – it can be satisfied by a regular method in a class, as class instances can be freely mutated. But yes, as it's currently written (without `mutating`, and you need to modify instance state in `push` and `pop`), it can only be satisfied by a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to conform to your `ProtoStack` protocol as it's currently written, your `push` and `pop` methods in your `MyStack` can't be `mutating`, as you cannot satisfy a non-mutating protocol requirement with a `mutating` struct/enum method. Therefore if you want these methods to be `mutating`, then you also need to mark them in the protocol as being so.

As the [Swift language guide says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID271) (emphasis mine):

> If you define a protocol instance method requirement that is intended to mutate instances of any type that adopts the protocol, mark the method with the mutating keyword as part of the protocol’s definition. **This enables structures and enumerations to adopt the protocol and satisfy that method requirement.**

A `mutating` method in a protocol requirement can either be satisfied by a `mutating`<sup>1</sup> instance method in a value type (e.g a struct or enum) or a regular instance method in a class, as class instances can be mutated freely.

<sup>1. A mutating protocol requirement can also be satisfied by a non-mutating method in a value type, as this doesn't break the contract with the protocol (nothing *depends* on a mutation actually taking place within that method).</sup>